# Create a new dataframe with every 2 columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python and I am struggling with this.

I want to create a number of new dataframes, each from columns in an existing dataframe.  The original has the format of Time, x1, Time2, x2...

I've gotten as far as a loop to search for 'Time'

```
for col in df.columns:
    if 'Time' in col:
```

I'd need to call the column found and the one next to it and assign it to a new dataframe which has the columns of ['Time', 'x1'] then loop through for every pair of Timen & xn.  I would like to name the dataframes by xn.

thanks for any help.

Comment: You can either use `pd.wide_to_long` or just pure `df.to_numpy().reshape(-1,2)`

Comment: At first, process your dataframe. Create a new empty list 'old_dataframe' and append a new list with your old dataframe data for every column. Then, just create a new dataframe based on your, already created, list. Like: 'df1 = pd.DataFrame([old_dataframe[0], old_dataframe[1]])', then 'df2 = pd.DataFrame([old_dataframe[2], old_dataframe[3])', til the end of your old_dataframe list. If you want, you can store your dataframes as a list of dataframes instead of 'df1, df2...'. Just create a new list and then append 'pd.DataFrame([old_data.....'

Comment: unfortunately my X1 example was bad.. the x variables are actually random strings of names which don't have a common theme.  so I'm not sure if wide_to_long will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, I think what you want is `df.iloc[<row index>, <column index>]`.

If your dataframe is always formatted as `Time1, x1, Time2, x2, ..., TimeN, xN` (as in you are always grabbing consecutive columns to make your new dataframe), you can use do something like the following:

```
df_1 = df.iloc[ : , [0,1] ]
```

The `:` in the `<row_index>` will select all rows, and the `[0,1]` in the `<column index>` is a list of column indexes that you want.

You could then loop over the number of columns in your original dataframe to grab each pair:

```
# number of columns in your dataframe
number_of_columns = len(df.columns)

# store the split dataframes in a list
split_dfs = []

# loop over column indexes with step size 2
for i in range(0, number_of_columns, 2):
    split_dfs.append(df.iloc[:, [i,i+1]])
```

Comment: This worked perfect!  One more question.. how do I call and save each dataframe in my split_dfs with to_csv ?

Comment: Pandas has a built in `df.to_csv()` method you can call. You can loop over `split_dfs` and call `.to_csv('path/file_name.csv')`.